# Tao-Analysis-II Lemma 3.8.5/Ex.3.8.1 3rd ed: Integral of multiply supported function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, solution-verification

### Context:

> A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be supported on $\left[ a, b \right]$ iff $f(x)=0$ for all $ x \notin \left[ a, b \right]$.
>
> If $f$ is continous and supported on $\left[a,b \right]$, we define the improper integral $\int_{\mathbb{R} } f =\int_{\left[a,b \right] } f $

### Problem:

> Lemma 3.8.5: If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and supported on an interval $ \left[ a, b \right]$ and is also supported on another interval $\left[ c,d \right]$ , then $\int_{ \left[ a , b\right] } f = \int_{\left[ c,d \right]}f $

We have two cases:

1. $\left[ a, b \right]$ and $\left[ c,d \right]$ have non empty intersection.
2. $\left[ a, b \right] $ and $ \left[ c, d \right]$ do not intersect.

#### Proof for each case:

1. **If the two sets have a non empty intersection**, then everything outside the intersection set is zero. Then the integral will equal to the integral over the intersection.
2. **For empty intersection:** Function is zero everywhere outside of $\left[c,d \right]$ and everywhere outside of $\left[ a,  b \right]$ from definition of a function being supported on an interval. This means the function is zero for the whole real line.

---

Does my proof look okay?

Comment: You could reduce the number of cases by considering case 1): [a,b] has non empty intersection with [c,d] and 2): [a,b] has empty intersection with [c,d].

Comment: Good point @Koro

Comment: I think you should incorporate your working for $1)$. Did you consider the case when $q=p$ and then what happens to $[q,p]$ and therefore to "$\int_{[q,p]} f$"?

Comment: I am not sure how one would deal with such a case as you've said @Koro

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, 1) also includes the case when 'intersection' is singleton. So 'the integral will equal to  the **integral over the intersection**.' does not make sense in that case. Also, note that you have nowhere used continuity of $f$.

So suppose that the non trivial intervals $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ intersect at exactly point. WLOG, suppose that $a<d$ and by non -trivial intervals it is meant that $a<b$ and $c<d$. So as per the assumption, $[a,b]\cap [c,d]=\{b\}=\{c\}$.

By definition of compact support, $f(x)=0$ for every $x\ne b$. By continuity of $f$ at $b$, it follows that $f(b)=0$.

So $f$ is the zero function. Therefore, $\int_{[a,b]}f=0=\int_{[c,d]}f\implies \int_{\mathbb R} f=0$.

Comment: Dear Koro, could you explain why it is neccesary that we use continuity? Why does the point I've mentioned not follow direct from definitions?

Comment: @Buraian: Please note again the definition of $\int_{\mathbb R}f$ . The definition defines $\int_{\mathbb R} f$ only when f is continuous and supported on ....

Comment: Oh I understand, I thought you meant that to prove a point, we need to use continuity as an intermediate fact. I do understand that the result is only defined for continous functs

Comment: @Buraian:  The equality $\int_{[a,b]}f=\int_{[c,d]} f=0$ does not require continuity at $b(=c)$. But the equality $\int_{\mathbb R} f= \int_{[a,b]}f=0$ does.

Comment: Does it hold true that $f$ will continue to be supported on intersection of intervals? I'll come back to this in a few hrs.

Comment: @Buraian: Yes, by definition.

Comment: Do you mean provable by definition? I think, it should go like this for x not in [a,b], f(x)=0 by definition, x not in [c,d] , f(x) = 0 by definition, then, f(x)=0 at the intersection by continuity. Correct?

Comment: @Buraian: I thought you asked about $f$ being supported on intersection of the two intervals. To show that f is supported on the intersection, $f$ is to be shown zero outside the intersection. That is, behavior of $f$ inside the intersection is not required for commenting on $f$ being supported on the intersection. If you do want to comment on value of $f$ in the intersection, then if the intersection is singleton then yes $f$ is zero at the intersection as you said.

Comment: I understand what you were saying now. I was thinking supported had continuity as well. Bruh. But yes, what you really meant is provable by definition

Comment: Hi Koro, I've edited my second poitn to add continuity. To double check, I do not need continuity for point 1. , correct?

Comment: @Buraian: Has $\int_{[p,q]} f$ when $p=q$ been defined in the text? If it has been defined as $0$ then continuity is not needed and your point 1 works just fine.  That's why I left a comment earlier to your post. I assumed that $\int_{[p,q]} f$ when $p=q$  has not been defined and therefore I used continuity in point 1 in case the intersection is singleton. Your point 2 doesn't look right. In point 2, you don't need continuity.

Comment: I think I finally understood everything you said. Thank you so much for your assistance

Comment: @Buraian: Glad that helped :-).